# Anyone available to burninate [availability] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[availability](/questions/tagged/availability) has no tag wiki and many of the questions are similar to:

- is email available?
- is internet/network available?
- do I have an item/room available?
- reports on who/what is availabile

This tag doesn't seem to have a lot of benefit, so is anyone available to help burninate [availability](/questions/tagged/availability)?  Or give some arguments for its purpose?

Comment: I tend to agree, but perhaps we need some tags like `application-availability` - the second question I got to on that tag is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066285/changing-app-availability-date-to-a-later-time-after-aproval), and it seems that it is a tangible concept in that case.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That was partly why I brought this to meta instead of just going through them all on my own.  If there is any worth to the availability tag or even if there is something else that should be created, we should have a discussion about it.

Comment: Standing by in the incineratocopter

Comment: @Won't I knew burninate would get your attention...is that your bat-signal?

Comment: Something about watching tags burn... it speaks to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Burned.  Random image inbound.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could +50 this just for the image!